# Conditional position-check in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, position, conditional-statements

I have an XSLT file which renders articles.  I'm passing a variable into the XSLT file which is supposed to limit the number of records output.  The trouble is, this 'limit' variable is optional - if it's not there the XSLT file needs to output all values; if the 'limit' variable is a number, then it needs to only output that number of items (presumably using a position() test).

Here's my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="limit" select="/macro/limit"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="allNodes" select="$localSiteRoot/descendant-or-self::*[articles != '']"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$allNodes">

    <div class="articleItem">
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="./articleHeader"/></h3>
      <xsl:if test="./articleSubheader != ''">
        <h4><xsl:value-of select="./articleSubheader"/></h4>
      </xsl:if>
    </div>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Clearly I could just do an XSLT choose around this and say

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when select="$limit!= ''">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $limit">
```

But then I'd need to repeat the code twice.  There must be a better way, perhaps using templates, but I just can't figure out how it would work and my XSLT isn't great.

Could anyone point me in the right direction with the best/neatest way to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$allNodes[not(position() > $limit)]">
```

**Explanation**:

1. **If the value of `$limit` is castable to a number**, then the expression in the `select` attribute above selects not more than `$limit` nodes.
2. **If the value of `$limits` isn't castable to a number** (e.g. empty or 'abc') then it is converted to NaN. By definition comparisons involving NaN are always `false()`, therefore the predicate `not(position() > $limit` is `true()` and in this case all nodes in `$allNodes` are selected.